# Finding URI's in a dataset

Tags: sparql, ttl

I am trying to find the URI's of ontologies in my dataset.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?ontology
WHERE {
  ?s ?ontology ?o
}
```

I'm aware the above code is incorrect, but I can see the properties this way and they do give me insight on URIs that contain the information I need. I just need some guidance on how to pull that data to find the uri for a whole ontology.

Comment: what is the "whole ontology"? You can get all subjects, predicates and objects via SPARQL - that's it. What else do you need besides the properties used in instance data?

Comment: For example,"<http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/editorList>"  this gives me the property of an ontology, like many others in my dataset but I don't want the URl for the property I want it for the ontology only.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm dumb, but I do not understand. What is "the ontology" then? Are you talking about the ontology IRI? `select * where {?ontologyIRI rdf:type owl:Ontology .}` But this triple does not always exists, only in OWL ontologies and it's not mandatory, it depends on the serializing tool. If this is not what you want, can you give a small example of data + expected result please?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any examples to show. The questions itself is difficult to understand for myself thats why I am asking others. All I know is the result is to show URI's in my dataset for ontologies being used within it, but not for a property in the ontology.